# Guzzle 6 live data streaming: How to?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Project is consuming URL API which is updating the data every seconds. By using Guzzle 6, How can i refresh the data in browser without AJAX?

```
    ...
    ...

    $un = 'admin';
    $pa = 'password';
    $base_uri = 'http://example.com:82';
    $uri1 = 'api/instant/connectopc';
    $uri2 = 'api/instant/displaydata?site=SITE';

    $cookieFile = 'jar.txt';
    $cookieJar = new FileCookieJar($cookieFile, true);
    $client = new Client([

        'base_uri' => $base_uri,
        'auth'=>[$un, $pa],
        'cookie'=>$cookieJar,
        'curl' => [
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'jar.txt',
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'jar.txt'
        ],

    ]);

   $connect = $client->get($uri1);  

   //live data to be refresh every seconds. How to do?

   $live= $client->get($uri2, ['cookies' => $cookieJar]); 
   ...
```

How to accomplish live data streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do any live streaming from the same page once browser has closed the connection. You have to open another connection. Via Ajax or another technology like [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for example if you need realtime data exchange.

Comment: can i use getAsync() function to do this?

Comment: @NKR What does it do? Where is it from? :)

Comment: Guzzle 6/php consume restful API. I read getAsync() can accomplish but how to?

Comment: @NKR You are approaching a problem from the wrong end. You need to think how to do it in browser first. Browser will either close the connection after it receives the page from PHP or you will have to leave it open and to provide data using HTML inside current page. Which will overflow browser's memory pretty quickly,

Answer (score 0):

You can't do live streaming with PHP .. You need to use a programming language like NodeJS :) .. PHP ends the connection at the end :)

Comment: Yes, but what about Guzzle 6, getAsync() function?